# iOS - How to properly read JSON file with umlauts

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am having difficulties converting a JSON file into an `NSDictionary` without losing umlauts.

```
{
"België": "5",
"Haïti": "45"
}
```

This is a short version of the contents of a .json file in my supporting files in Xcode.
I need to convert them to an `NSDictionary` without losing those umlauts.

```
NSString *file =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"countries_and_rates" ofType:@"json"];
NSString *cr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

After that, I give `cr` to this method:

```
+ (NSDictionary*)jsonFromData:(NSData*)data {
    if([self isEmpty:data] || ![data isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
        return nil;

    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(!str)
        return nil;

    NSError* error;
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    if(error)
        NSLog(@"************** Error: jsonFromData: %@/%@", error.localizedDescription, error);
    if([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        return json;
    else if([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:json forKey:@"results"];

    return @{};
}
```

If someone could help me and tell me what I am doing wrong.
FYI: tried all kinds of encoding, such as NSISO and NSUTF

Comment: What are you seeing instead? Are the accented characters being converted into non-accented characters, or nonsense values, or what?

Comment: Why are you not reading the file directly as NSData?  And you understand, of course, that NSLog may not correctly represent non-ASCII characters.

Comment: How are you passing cr, which is an NSString*, to jsonFromData, which expects NSData? Just read the file as NSData and pass it.

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon I'm seeing regular letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mess around with encodings, let the framework figure it out for you:

```
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
    NSError *error = nil;
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: tried this, still seeing regular letters without umlauts :(

Comment: edit: 

it was working, my mistake was that i forgot hardcoded json name.

it should be localized "countries_and_rates_NL.json"